# Kivy add widgets on different sides of the Layout

Tags: python, kivy

I have a chat app that uses a widget to print out messages. I want to print these on different sides, so the user input goes on the right and the answer goes on the left. Furthermore, I want the chat box to scroll to the new message. Here is my code, where I tried to use a StackLayout, only to realise it doesn't work:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Message(Widget):
    pass

class KatApp(App):
    def post(self):
        msg = self.root.ids.usrinp.text
        if len(msg) > 0:
            self.root.ids.chatbox.orientation = 'tb-rl'
            msgbox = Message()
            msgbox.ids.mlab.text = msg
            self.root.ids.chatbox.add_widget(msgbox)
            self.root.ids.scrlv.scroll_to(msgbox)
            self.root.ids.usrinp.text = ''
    def resp(self,msg):
        if len(msg) > 0:
            ansr = msg
            self.root.ids.chatbox.orientation = 'tb-lr'
            ansrbox = Message()
            ansrbox.ids.mlab.text = str(ansr)
            self.root.ids.chatbox.add_widget(ansrbox)
            self.root.ids.scrlv.scroll_to(ansrbox)
            self.root.ids.usrinp.text = ''

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string('''
<Message@Widget>:
    size_hint: None, None
    height: mlab.height
    width: mlab.width
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.7
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        id: mlab
        center: root.center
        padding: 10, 10
        markup: True
        text_size: (None, None)
        text: ''
        haligh: 'left'
        valign: 'top'
        size_hint: (1, None)
        size: self.texture_size
        color: 0, 0, 0

ScreenManager:
    Screen:

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            ScrollView:

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1, 1, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                StackLayout:
                    id: chatbox
                    padding: 10, 10
                    orientation: 'tb-rl'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                padding: 10, 10, 10, 10
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 50

                BoxLayout:
                    id: inpbox
                    height: max(40, scrlv.height)
                    size_hint: 0.9, None

                    ScrollView:
                        id: scrlv
                        width: inpbox.width - 15
                        x: inpbox.x + 10
                        y: inpbox.y
                        height: 
                            (len(usrinp._lines)+1) * usrinp.line_height - 5 \
                            if (len(usrinp._lines)+1 <= 5) \
                            else 5 * usrinp.line_height - 5

                        TextInput:
                            id: usrinp
                            valign: 'middle'
                            halign: 'left'
                            font_size: 16
                            multiline: True
                            size_hint: scrlv.size_hint_x, None
                            padding: 10, 0, 10, 0


                Button:
                    id: post
                    border: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    size: 40, 40
                    size_hint: None, None
                    on_press:
                        root.inp = usrinp.text
                        app.post()
                    on_release:
                        app.resp(root.inp)
''')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KatApp().run()
```

For the sake of this example, the button on the bottom right sends the user input on_press and answers with the same input on_release.

Also, is it possible to make a maximum width for the message widget, like, if it reaches the middle of the page, it should go on the next line?

One more thing that I'm having a hard time figuring out would be the TextInput. It seems that, with the multiline option, when a word is long enough to go on the next line and I try to delete it, some space remains there and it keeps the box from resizing. To reproduce this, just type "aaaaaaaaaa" until it is on line 3 and try to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap the width of the widget try this:

## Function to read text and create label

```
  def Sender_chat_bubble():
```

> Measure the length of the unwrapped text

```
    Measure = Label(text=self.chatinputfield.text)
    Measure.texture_update()

    if Measure.texture_size[0]== 0 or self.chatinputfield.text=='':
        return 0
```

> if the text is not long, keep same width + 10 for the padding I added

```
    elif Measure.texture_size[0]<250:
        xsize = Measure.texture_size[0] 
        chatbubble = ChatBubble_Send(text=self.chatinputfield.text, width=xsize+10, padding_y=10, padding_x=10)
```

> If the unwrapped text is longer than your limit(250 here) , lets wrap it to 260 (250 + 10 padding)

```
else:
     chatbubble = ChatBubble_Send(text=self.chatinputfield.text, width=250+10, padding_y=10, padding_x=10)
```

## Class to make a color behing the label

```
class ColorLabelSEND(Label):
    bgcolor = ListProperty([0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ColorLabelSEND, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            r, g, b, a = self.bgcolor
            Color(r, g, b, a)
            self.rect = Rectangle(
                            size=self.size,
                            pos=self.pos)
            self.bind(size=self._update_rect,
                      pos=self._update_rect)

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size
```

## Class to wrap the text and label

```
class ChatBubble_Send(ColorLabelSEND):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChatBubble_Send, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)

        #Constrain horizontally to size of label and free vertically
        self.text_size = (self.width, None) 
        self.width = self.width + 15

    def on_texture_size(self,*args):
       self.texture_update()
       self.height = self.texture_size[1]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: It has been 2 years since I looked at this project, but I assume the new Kivy version made it simpler to do this. I am unsure how well this works, but I will mark it as the answer in case people search for this in the future. Thanks for answering such an old question!

Comment: You are most welcome! I am also making a chat app and for me it works fine. I havent seen yet such a feature from kivy or kivyMD, so I am still using the same. On windows and MacOS it works fine, but I noticed on android the text dissapears from the label in a random manner.

Answer (score 1):

Writing on each side can be done using a BoxLayout.

```
def post(self):
    msg = self.root.ids.usrinp.text
    if len(msg) > 0:
        msgbox = Message()
        msgbox.ids.mlab.text = msg
        msgbox.pos_hint = {'right': 1}
        self.root.ids.chatbox.add_widget(msgbox)
        self.root.ids.scrlv.scroll_to(msgbox)
        self.root.ids.usrinp.text = ''

def resp(self, msg):
    if len(msg) > 0:
        ansr = msg
        ansrbox = Message()
        ansrbox.ids.mlab.text = str(ansr)
        ansrbox.pos_hint = {'x': 0}
        self.root.ids.chatbox.add_widget(ansrbox)
        self.root.ids.scrlv.scroll_to(ansrbox)
        self.root.ids.usrinp.text = ''
```

And in the builder:

```
        ScrollView:

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: chatbox
                padding: 10, 10
                spacing: 5
```

After adding `pos_hint: {'right': 1}` to the input widget, the text now goes on the right side, like this:

[image]

The problem now remains with the width of the widget:

[image]

I tried setting the width of the widget to `max(root.width, mlab.width)`, but it doesn't work. Also, now, scrolling up doesn't work.